# Excel data into one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I work for a charity and not too familiar with excel.

The data is is imported from our website into a spreadsheet but the orders are not separated into rows and columns as I would like. Is it possible to arrange multiple data in rows into one column? Not every row has the same number of entries.I have used text to columns to convert csv data into columns.

Thank you

[image]

Edit

This is how the import appears on the csv file:

Orders              Product Name
50, 30              water aid, food parcel
5                   general
20                  medical
1, 5, 20, 100       general, water aid, medical, food

AND This is what I would like it to look like.

Orders  Product name
50      water aid
30      food parcel
5       general
20      medical
1       general
5       water aid
20      medical
100     food

Really not sure how i can import the csv format here, anyone help?

Comment: This might be solved at import; The original data appears to be separated by a tab or space or sim, and that is the same as columns in Excel. Can you modify the import or is that something set up by someone else?

Comment: As @Ack implies, can you provide a sample of the original CSV file?  Preferable as text within your question.  It might be easier to modify at that point.

Comment: Hi @faisalv,, this needs VBA (Macro), if u are comfortable with it then please [edit] your post and specified that Macro will also work for you as well as add new TAG `VBA` to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the import.

Comment: @faisalv,, check my post for what you are looking for. ☺

Answer (score 0):

*VBA Macro solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Press **Alt+F11** to open VB editor.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code as standard module.

---

```
    Sub SplitData()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRg1 As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xRet As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a column", "Split Data", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "You can't select multiple columns", , "Split Data"
            Exit Sub
            End If

            Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (select single cell):", "Split Data", , , , , , 8)
            Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")

            If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
                xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                For Each xCell In xRg
                    xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
                    xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(i, 0), xRg1.Offset(i + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
                    i = i + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
                Next
                Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
            End Sub
```

---

- Hit **Alt+Q** to return to Sheet.
- **S**ave file as, **M**acro Enabled (`.xlsm` ).
- **R**UN the Macro.
- Select required cells from Col A.

[image]

---

- Finish with **O**k.

---

[image]

- Select single cell for OUTPUT & finish with **O**k.

[image]

---

- **R**UN the Macro again and repeat the procedure for Product column.
- You get final output.

[image]

**N.B.** *This macro works for, one column at a time.*